# Automapper Ignore nested property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, ef-core-2.0

I've search the internet for a few hours now and can't seem to figure out any solutions for myself, or understand some of other similar answers I'm finding.

All I'm trying to do is ignore property from a nested object in my AutoMapper. Here's a small overview of the Models I'm working with (I removed some properties to make them a bit smaller for the purposes of this question).

```
public class Product 
{
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }

  public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDto 
{
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }

  public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string LabelColor { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDto
{
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string LabelColor { get; set; }
}
```

Basically all I want is my automapper to ignore the Created property coming from the Category class anytime a Product is queried via API. The closest I've to achieving this is by having the whole Category object ignored when queried.

Here is the current mapping configuration for my Product class

```
public class ProductMapping: Profile
{
  public ProductMapping()
  {
    CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
       .ReverseMap()
       .ForMember(x => x.ProductId, o => o.Ignore());
  }
}
```

I was able to null out the whole object by putting `.ForPath(x => x.Category.Created, o => o.Ignore()` before `.ReverseMap()`

I should note that of course the classes and mapper class are distributed through multiple files and the CategoryMapping class looks the same as the ProductMapping. It is removing the Created property, though that is expected.

If anyone can help isolate my issue, or demonstrate a better way to achieve this I am open to suggestions. Till then I will continue trying to figure out this issue. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly if you want to ignore the Created field from Category class then you should maybe put the ignore logic when mapping from CategoryDto -> Category or vice versa and mapping from ProductDto <-> remains the same.

```
 CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
       .ReverseMap()
```

```
   CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>()
       .ReverseMap()
       .ForMember(x => x.Created, o => o.Ignore());
```

Comment: I have tried to add the additional logic in my CategoryMapping by ignoring the Created field. But I still get that property when querying for a Product. I did have to put it after the ReverseMap() method because an issue was thrown for CategoryDto not having a Created property (which makes sense)

I'm not completely sure if this issue could lying within my controller for the Product class, but I feel like Automapper is built to take care of this.

Comment: I do want to add that I do see this being an issue with a couple of models. When I query one of my Models I would expect all the nested objects to be returned as their respective DTOs

Answer (score 0):

May have answered my own question, but what I had to do was switch the Data type in my ProductDto from Category to CategoryDto. I was under the assumption that Automapper would sort of take care of that itself.

Sorry for that! Thank you to person who took the time to give me an answer aswell!